# Pre-Build command returns -1, when script returns 0

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, pre-build-event, prebuild

I've configured Visual Studio to run a pre-build script.
My pre-build script command is like this:

```
call $(SolutionDir)test.bat
```

My bat file is like this:

```
@echo error CS0006: hello bingo
```

and I get the same error when I explicitly return 0, like so

```
@echo error CS0006: hello bingo
exit 0
```

(including variations of exit, such as **EXIT /b 0** etc.)

As intended Visual Studio's Error List window gets the nice error message I wished from the script and displays:

```
CS0006 hello bingo
```

in the correct format.

However, I then get another error message subsequently stating

```
"The command @echo error CS0006: hello bingo exits with error code -1".
```

Now this is an error I do not wish to get.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you reporting an error to stdout? Why are you reporting an error and not also returning an error code?

Comment: Is that really your entire batch file?  What's the point of it?